# How to see the speedup when using Cloudinary "direct upload" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I have a **RoR** web app that allow users upload images and use **Cloudinary** as cloud storage. I read their document and find a cool way called "[direct uploading](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser)" which reduce my server's loading. To my knowledge, the spirit is changing workflow

> image -> server -> Cloudinary

to

> image -> Cloudinary

and my server only store an Cloudinary url to database, not the image file (Tell me if I'm wrong, thx).

**So my question is, how to check whether I have changed to "direct uploading" method successfully?** Open element inspector to see time cost for each POST and GET requests? Other better options?

**I expect big advances via this way, but how can I feel it?**

Thanks form a rookie =)

# The app is deployed on **heroku**.

# Doesn't change to direct uploading method yet.

# This app is private, only serve for around 10 people.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed (and it is very recommended to) bypass your server and let Cloudinary take care of the upload processing directly. This indeed lowers the processing of your server to simply store the uploaded image's details, and the image is directly stored in your Cloudinary account. This indeed quickens the upload process. You can test out the [sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album) which demonstrates both server-side and client-side uploads.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try it.